# Slack API React: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, slack-api

I know it's a common question, but I already tried the solution from same questions to no avail. I just wanted to sent a message from react app to slack channel using webhook, but somehow my input message is considered null/undefined.

My code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  async function submitForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const webhookUrl = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/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';

    const data = {
        "text": `${message}`,
    }

    let res = await axios.post(webhookUrl, JSON.stringify(data), {
        withCredentials: false,
        transformRequest: [(data, headers) => {
            delete headers.post["Content-Type"]
            return data
        }]
    })

    if (res.status === 200) {
        alert("Message Sent!")

        //clear state so text boxes clear
        setMessage('');
    } else {
        alert("There was an error.  Please try again later.")
    }

}

  return (
    <div className="flex">
      <div className="w-1/2 container mx-auto mt-5">
        <form className="bg-white shadow-md rounded px-8 pt-6 pb-8 mb-4 self-center">
          <label className="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2" htmlFor="message">
            Message
        </label>
          <textarea
            className="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white"
            id="message"
            type="message"
            placeholder="Write your message here"
            value={message}
            onChange={(e) => { setMessage(e.target.value) }}
          ></textarea>

          <button
            className="mt-4 shadow bg-purple-500 hover:bg-purple-400 focus:shadow-outline focus:outline-none text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
            onClick={(e) => submitForm(e)}
          >
            Submit
        </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

here is the error message

```
Cannot convert undefined or null to object
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at axios__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.default.post.transformRequest (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:41:24)
    at transform (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:42455:15)
    at Object.forEach (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:44111:10)
    at Object.transformData (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:42454:53)
    at Axios.dispatchRequest (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:42239:75)
    at Axios.request (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:41683:77)
    at Axios.httpMethod [as post] (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:41717:19)
    at Function.wrap [as post] (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:42816:15)
    at submitForm (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:38:67)
    at onClick (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:83:25)
```

I think the problem came from:

```
JSON.stringify(data)
```

Comment: message is not the problem you convert it to the string 'undefined' or 'null' should it be undefined or null. also your stack trace leads you inside axios http method. so you should check on the transformRequest option

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem come from :

```
delete headers.post["Content-Type"]
```

`headers.post` seems not to be defined. Perhaps you should access "Content-Type" directly from `headers` ?